# The current data adapter provider does not support renumbering interactions

Tags: xdb, experience-analytics

We are in the process of resetting up our Analytics on 8.2 Update 2.   While reviewing logs, I noticed this error in the log that did not occur in our old 8.0 instance.

> 3084 08:49:45 INFO  MARKETO: [Method: Marketo > GenerateCookie]
>   [username: user@example.com]
>
> 3084 08:49:45 ERROR General error when submitting contact.
>       Exception: System.NotImplementedException
>       Message: The current data adapter provider does not support renumbering interactions.
>       Source: Sitecore.Analytics.DataAccess
>          at Sitecore.Analytics.DataAccess.DataAdapterProvider.RenumberInteractions(ID
>   contactId)
>          at Sitecore.Analytics.Data.ContactRepository.ReconcileContact(Contact
>   contact, LeaseOwner owner, TimeSpan duration)
>          at Sitecore.Analytics.Tracking.ContactManager.SubmitContact(Contact
>   contact, ContactSaveOptions options, Contact& realContact)
>
> 3084 08:49:45 INFO  MySite.Analytics.ContactManagement.TrackContact:
>   Known contact identified: user@example.com
>
> 3084 08:49:45 INFO  SITECORE ANALYTICS: Outcome added for contact:
>   {F5A28B73-F58B-44F2-A011-4D76BB4984C9} for the definition:
>   {52054874-4767-47DC-8099-8C08BFA307AA}

The code that appears to be raising this...

```
controller.Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
Sitecore.Diagnostics.Log.Info("MARKETO: [Method: Marketo > GenerateCookie] [username: " + username + "]", this);

try
{
    ContactManagement contactManagement = new ContactManagement();
    bool trackedContact = contactManagement.TrackContact(username, true);
    bool updatedPreferred = contactManagement.UpdatePreferred(username);
    ThirdParty thirdParty = new ThirdParty();
    bool syncedThirdParty = thirdParty.Sync(username, "marketo");
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Sitecore.Diagnostics.Log.Error("MySite.BusinessLogic.Marketo.GenerateCookie (Analytics): [" + ex.StackTrace + "]", ex, this);
}
return true;
```

and...

```
public bool TrackContact(string identifier, bool addMarketingLead = false) {
    try
    {
        Tracker.Current.Session.Identify(identifier);
        var contact = Tracker.Current.Session.Contact;
        contact.ContactSaveMode = ContactSaveMode.AlwaysSave;
        if (contact.Identifiers.IdentificationLevel != ContactIdentificationLevel.Known)
        {
           contact.Identifiers.IdentificationLevel = ContactIdentificationLevel.Known;
        }
        Log.Info("MySite.Analytics.ContactManagement.TrackContact: Known contact identified: " + identifier, this);
        if (addMarketingLead == true) 
        {
            bool addedMarketingLeadOutcome = new Outcomes().AddMarketingLead(contact.ContactId);
        }
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Log.Error("MySite.Analytics.ContactManagement.TrackContact: [" + ex.StackTrace + "]", ex, this);
        return false;
    }
}
```

You will see that we log that the cookie was created okay, then we log that the Known contact has been identified.  So the error appears to be occurring between those two `Log.Info` calls.

Any ideas why this error about renumbering interactions is now being raised?

Answer (score 1):

After some investigation in `Sitecore.Analytics.dll` and `Sitecore.Analytics.DataAccess.dll` I found that it is called by the `Tracker.Current.Session.Identify` method. So actually the stacktrace is:

1. `Sitecore.Analytics.Tracking.ContactManager.FlushContactToXdb(Contact contact)`
2. `Sitecore.Analytics.Tracking.ContactManager.SubmitContact(Contact contact, ContactSaveOptions options, Contact& realContact)`
   ...

This method was totally different in Sitecore 8.0.

So at the end the `RenumberInteractions(ID contactId)` throws the exception.

```
public virtual void RenumberInteractions(ID contactId)
{
  throw new NotImplementedException("The current data adapter provider does not support renumbering interactions.");
}
```

I tested locally on a clean instance and I don't have this error so maybe setting is different. I think somehow the `contact.IsTemporaryInstance` is true. And that's why it is going to that branch. I suggest to decompile the these 2 assemblies and check what happens there. Especailly I am talking about the `Tracker.Current.Session.Identify(string userName)` method. Something happens in this branch I guess:

```
if (contact1 == null || contact1.ContactId == Guid.Empty)
  {
    bool flag = false;
    if (this.Contact.Identifiers.IdentificationLevel != ContactIdentificationLevel.Known)
    {
      if (this.Contact.ContactSaveMode != ContactSaveMode.NeverSave && !this.Settings.IsTransient && (ContactClassification.IsHuman(this.Contact.System.Classification) || ContactClassification.IsAutoDetectedRobot(this.Contact.System.Classification)))
      {
        if (this.Contact.System.VisitCount > 1)
          contact1 = contactManager.LoadContactReadOnly(this.Contact.ContactId);
        if (contact1 == null)
        {
          contact1 = contactManager.CreateContact(this.Contact.ContactId);
          contact1.IsTemporaryInstance = true;
        }
        flag = true;
      }
      else
        contact1 = this.Contact;
    }
    else
    {
      flag = true;
      ID id = string.Equals(this.Contact.Identifiers.Identifier, userName, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) ? TypeExtensions.ToID(this.Contact.ContactId) : ID.NewID;
      contact1 = contactManager.CreateContact(id);
    }
    contact1.Identifiers.IdentificationLevel = ContactIdentificationLevel.Known;
    contact1.Identifiers.Identifier = userName;
    if (flag)
      contactManager.FlushContactToXdb(contact1);
  }
```